# Cannot activate bitlocker on removable disk

Tags: windows, encryption, group-policy, bitlocker, usb-storage

I've activated BitLocker on all hard drives on my PC, without any problem. I've also modified the group policy for inserting a PIN when the computer starts.

But I'm having some problems when trying to activate bitlocker in a USB external hard drive. When I try to activate it I obtain an error:

[image: error]

It says (not the exact English sentence I presume, I'm translating on the fly) that's impossible to apply the group policy settings related to start options of bitlocker because they're in conflict; for further information contact the system administrator.

Now I've tried to play a bit with the bitlocker group policy options for removable drives but with no results.

Is there a way to check what are the group policy settings that cause the problem? And how can I fix it?

Comment: "Is there a way to check what are the group policy settings that cause the problem? " - Check which BitLocker GPOs you have enabled on the system through the Local Group Policy editor. Have you contacted your IT Administrator? Is this machine connected to a Active Directory domain? Is there any chance you can give us a exact English translation? If you are connected to an AD Domain, are you an Administrator on it?  Instead of submitting a comment you should [edit] your question.  You find it helpful to enable the English language pack to acomplish the task of providing us an exact translation.

Comment: @Ramhound The translation done by the OP is correct and adequate .

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I found the translated English message and I would argue it was substanially different. I suspect I could answer this question if I had additional information. Of course my research was yesterday, so it would difficult, to find my research again at this point.

Comment: @Ramhound I do understand Italian as well as pretty much any other Latin derived language under the Sun. If you found something "substantially different" then it isn't the same message. It can be directly translated to English almost word for word (BTW, English is ~40% Latin derived via Normand so, really, NOT that hard).

Comment: I thought it was French so that might have had something to do with it. I know neither Italian or French so both look Greek to me. Yes; That was a joke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Bitlocker GPOs are reflected in the registry under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE
->export that key
->delete it
->encrypt
->import that key again
That works.

There are bugs within BL GPOs that produce conflicts with removable drives although the settings for them are not in conflict! I have analysed that before.